# No login screen after uninstalling lightdm

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm, login-screen

I did

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

After logging out I no longer get the login screen. Just a blank screen with a blinking cursor top left. Rebooting results in the same.

I'd like to restore to the Unity login. I'm running ubuntu 16.04. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you able to log in at one of the CLI virtual terminals (Ctrl-Alt-F1 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the CLI virtual terminal. I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and unity which at least got me back to where I was prior.

Answer (score 0):

The black screen appears because the Ubuntu boot process defaults to tty7, the terminal where the graphical login (lightdm) would normally be running.

To get to a login prompt, you can switch manually to one of the other ttys using `Ctrl+Alt+F1` through `Ctrl+Alt+F6`.

For a permanent fix, edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` as root:

```sh
sudo vim /etc/grub.d/10_linux
```

Find the line that says

```
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
```

and replace it with

```
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
```

To apply the setting, you need to run `update-grub` as root:

```sh
sudo update-grub
```

This changes the default tty to tty1, where a text login prompt is usually running.

Answer (score 0):

I also did the same thing.. that is removed lightdm..
My machine was showing me login using shell ...

1. Logged in using username and password in shell.
2. just installed the lightdm again or install gdm3..

   sudo apt-get install gdm3

It prompted me to choose between gdm3 or lightdm...
Select gdm3 and press enter
And then
Run sudo reboot.
It will login using gdm3 gui.
Now I was able to remove lightdm succet.

Answer (score 0):

to change the default display manager on a Ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

related: https://tecadmin.net/switching-display-manager-in-ubuntu/