# unity-greeter hangs for a sec, other oddities

Tags: 16.04, unity-greeter

After unity-greeter comes up (i.e. login screen appears), it will hang for ~5 seconds before responding to any typing I do (the keyboard input does buffer while hanging). After the delay, I get a conga sound then the cursor appears in the password field.

The other oddity is that for the background/wallpaper, I get just a grid of dots. I'm new to this, but while researching how to set a custom wallpaper I'm getting the impression that *some* images should appear with a default unity-greeter installation, and the purple dots is supposed to be a

I looked through logs in /var/log/lightdm and nothing occurs to me, though again, I'm new to this.

Something feels off. Any suggestions on permissions, logs, etc. to go looking? You can also tell me that the ~5 secs delay and conga are normal. Thanks.

My machine specs

- Intel i5-6600K 3.5 GHz quad core
- 16 GB mem
- GPU: Nvidia GeoForce GTX 1070
- 20 GB SSD disk allocated

Comment: The ~5 secs I wouldn't say it's "normal" but also not unheard of. You told us nothing about your hardware and that can have a great impact on performance and boot time. Please [edit] and add you hardware specs, especially graphics and driver you may have installed.

Comment: This may or may not be playing a role: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905564/no-login-screen-after-uninstalling-lightdm (there was a problem already)

Comment: Thanks, added specs. This problem was occurring prior to me posting the other question you refer to.

Comment: OK, GTX1070, as expected. It requires proprietary drivers for optimal performance. Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers. Select and apply both the recommended Nvidia drivers and the CPU microcode. Reboot.

Comment: Okay, seems to have gotten rid of the lag, thanks much.